# Using sed to edit complex ids from large text file

Tags: sed

I want to change the IDs in this large text file so that only the second field in between the ';' stays. See below:

Go from this:

```
> AT1G01030;AT1G01030.2;atRTD2::1:11648-13714
> TTATATACAAAATTGAAAAGATGCGAGTTTCAACATGGTGACAAAAGCCTAATGATGATGAACATCAAGAAACATGTCGGAAAAAAAAATCATAACCAAAAAAACGAAGAAGATCGTTTTTTCTTCCTCTCACTAGCTAGAATCTAATACCCTTAGAAAAATTACTAATGAAACAATATAAAGAGAGATTCAAAACAAGAAGATGATGAAACTTCTCATGGATTGAAATTGAGAGAAAGTGAAGACTTCCCTTTCTTAGCAAATTGATCATCATCGCCATCATCACCATCATCATTATCA
> AT1G01040;AT1G01040.1;Araport::1:23120-31227
> GTGGAAAACAGACCAGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATTGGCGTGTTTCGTACGGTCTATCTAACCCTAATCTGTCACAAAACACTCTTCTTCTCTCACCCCTTTTTCTGGGTTTATTCAATTCTCGTGCTTTTGGTTCTGTTTTCTTCTCTGGGGATTTGGTTTTCTTGAGTGAGTTTTTCTCCTCTTTCTTATGTTCTTGATTTGATTATTATATAGAATTAT
> AT1G01040-AT1G01046;AT1G01040-AT1G01046.1;Isoseq::1:23134-31211
> AGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATT
```

to this:

```
> AT1G01030.2
> TTATATACAAAATTGAAAAGATGCGAGTTTCAACATGGTGACAAAAGCCTAATGATGATGAACATCAAGAAACATGTCGGAAAAAAAAATCATAACCAAAAAAACGAAGAAGATCGTTTTTTCTTCCTCTCACTAGCTAGAATCTAATACCCTTAGAAAAATTACTAATGAAACAATATAAAGAGAGATTCAAAACAAGAAGATGATGAAACTTCTCATGGATTGAAATTGAGAGAAAGTGAAGACTTCCCTTTCTTAGCAAATTGATCATCATCGCCATCATCACCATCATCATTATCA
> AT1G01040.1
> GTGGAAAACAGACCAGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATTGGCGTGTTTCGTACGGTCTATCTAACCCTAATCTGTCACAAAACACTCTTCTTCTCTCACCCCTTTTTCTGGGTTTATTCAATTCTCGTGCTTTTGGTTCTGTTTTCTTCTCTGGGGATTTGGTTTTCTTGAGTGAGTTTTTCTCCTCTTTCTTATGTTCTTGATTTGATTATTATATAGAATTAT
> AT1G01040-AT1G01046.1
> AGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATT
```

How would you do this using sed?

I got as far as matching my region of interest with `;[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+;`

Comment: Looks like CSV with a semicolon as field separator. Consider using a tool aimed at CSV instead of a general tool for text. That said, couldn't you find anything in the `sed` docs that replaces content in a line?

Comment: Hi Ulrich. Thanks for the tip. I tried but since I am a biologist I utterly failed :P, hence asking for help

Comment: If this is actually FASTA format, you should have kept the `>` header indicator on the header lines; it's important for the integrity of the format. `sed 's/^>[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*/>\1/' file`

Comment: Yes, tripleee! You are completely right. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: That `>` removal was probably my fault: It looked like OP had accidentally formatted the code as a blockquote, so I removed them and put them into a code block ... my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]][^;]*;([^;]*).*/\1/' input_file
> AT1G01030.2
> TTATATACAAAATTGAAAAGATGCGAGTTTCAACATGGTGACAAAAGCCTAATGATGATGAACATCAAGAAACATGTCGGAAAAAAAAATCATAACCAAAAAAACGAAGAAGATCGTTTTTTCTTCCTCTCACTAGCTAGAATCTAATACCCTTAGAAAAATTACTAATGAAACAATATAAAGAGAGATTCAAAACAAGAAGATGATGAAACTTCTCATGGATTGAAATTGAGAGAAAGTGAAGACTTCCCTTTCTTAGCAAATTGATCATCATCGCCATCATCACCATCATCATTATCA
> AT1G01040.1
> GTGGAAAACAGACCAGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATTGGCGTGTTTCGTACGGTCTATCTAACCCTAATCTGTCACAAAACACTCTTCTTCTCTCACCCCTTTTTCTGGGTTTATTCAATTCTCGTGCTTTTGGTTCTGTTTTCTTCTCTGGGGATTTGGTTTTCTTGAGTGAGTTTTTCTCCTCTTTCTTATGTTCTTGATTTGATTATTATATAGAATTAT
> AT1G01040-AT1G01046.1
> AGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NF>1{$0="> " $2} 1' file
> AT1G01030.2
> TTATATACAAAATTGAAAAGATGCGAGTTTCAACATGGTGACAAAAGCCTAATGATGATGAACATCAAGAAACATGTCGGAAAAAAAAATCATAACCAAAAAAACGAAGAAGATCGTTTTTTCTTCCTCTCACTAGCTAGAATCTAATACCCTTAGAAAAATTACTAATGAAACAATATAAAGAGAGATTCAAAACAAGAAGATGATGAAACTTCTCATGGATTGAAATTGAGAGAAAGTGAAGACTTCCCTTTCTTAGCAAATTGATCATCATCGCCATCATCACCATCATCATTATCA
> AT1G01040.1
> GTGGAAAACAGACCAGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATTGGCGTGTTTCGTACGGTCTATCTAACCCTAATCTGTCACAAAACACTCTTCTTCTCTCACCCCTTTTTCTGGGTTTATTCAATTCTCGTGCTTTTGGTTCTGTTTTCTTCTCTGGGGATTTGGTTTTCTTGAGTGAGTTTTTCTCCTCTTTCTTATGTTCTTGATTTGATTATTATATAGAATTAT
> AT1G01040-AT1G01046.1
> AGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATT
```

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*/> \1/' file
> AT1G01030.2
> TTATATACAAAATTGAAAAGATGCGAGTTTCAACATGGTGACAAAAGCCTAATGATGATGAACATCAAGAAACATGTCGGAAAAAAAAATCATAACCAAAAAAACGAAGAAGATCGTTTTTTCTTCCTCTCACTAGCTAGAATCTAATACCCTTAGAAAAATTACTAATGAAACAATATAAAGAGAGATTCAAAACAAGAAGATGATGAAACTTCTCATGGATTGAAATTGAGAGAAAGTGAAGACTTCCCTTTCTTAGCAAATTGATCATCATCGCCATCATCACCATCATCATTATCA
> AT1G01040.1
> GTGGAAAACAGACCAGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATTGGCGTGTTTCGTACGGTCTATCTAACCCTAATCTGTCACAAAACACTCTTCTTCTCTCACCCCTTTTTCTGGGTTTATTCAATTCTCGTGCTTTTGGTTCTGTTTTCTTCTCTGGGGATTTGGTTTTCTTGAGTGAGTTTTTCTCCTCTTTCTTATGTTCTTGATTTGATTATTATATAGAATTAT
> AT1G01040-AT1G01046.1
> AGAAGAGAGAGGAAGACGAAGAGAGAAACAGAACAGAGTAGGGATCGATAGACCGTGGAATCTCAGAATCACAAACACTTTGCAAAAGGGTTTTCAATTCCTATTTATTTACAAAGAAATCATCAATAGTAGTGGTCTCTAGGGTTTTGCTTGCTCTTCTTCGTGACCCCTTTTTACCTGCAAACAACAACTTCAAAATT
```